# `ticklabel style` and `extra y tick style` typesetting tick labels inconsistently

Tags: pgfplots

I have the graph of two lines that are reflections of each other across the `x`-axis. The y-intercepts are `(0,-2)` and `(0,2)`. I use `ticklabel style` to typeset `2` and `extra y tick style` to typeset `-2` on the `y`-axis. Why are they not equidistant from the `y`-axis?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3.5in, axis equal image, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-14,xmax=6,
    ymin=-5,ymax=5,
    ticklabel style={anchor=south east, xshift=2pt, yshift=-2pt, font=\tiny},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={2},
    extra y ticks={-2},
    extra y tick style={tick label style={anchor=north east, xshift=2pt, yshift=2pt, font=\tiny}},
    extra y tick labels={\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}2},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=\textit{x}, ylabel=\textit{y},
    axis line style={shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=12.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=12.5pt, anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[latex-latex, domain=-14:6] {(1/2) * x + 2};
\addplot[latex-latex, dashed, domain=-14:6] {-(1/2) * x - 2};

\coordinate (A) at (-12,-4);
\coordinate (B) at (0,2);
\coordinate (C) at (-12,4);
\coordinate (D) at (0,-2);

\end{axis}

%A "pin" is drawn between the label for the line with slope 1/2 and the the line.
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (A) -- ($(A) +({atan(-2)}:0.5)$);
\draw node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(A) +({atan(-2)}:0.5)$){$-2x + y = 2$};


%A "pin" is drawn between the label for the line with slope -1/2 and the the line.
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (C) -- ($(C) +({atan(2)}:0.5)$);
\draw node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(C) +({atan(2)}:0.5)$){$2x + y = -2$};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I just realized, `xshift`s are cumulative. If one adds more than one `xshift` to the same node, the total shift is not the value of the last shift, but the sum of the two. An example to illustrate this:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (0,-1) grid (2,1);

% no xshift
\node [yshift=1cm,draw] {1};
% one xshift
\node [yshift=0cm,xshift=1cm,draw] {2};
% two xshift
\node [yshift=-1cm,xshift=1cm,xshift=1cm,draw] {3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the `3` node is shifted by 2cm, as it has `xshift=1cm` twice.

The same thing happens for your `extra tick`, because `ticklabel style` is short for `every tick label/.append style`. Key is `append`, which means that the arguments to `ticklabel style` is added to the end of the `every tick label` style, without changing the existing parts of the style.

Hence, the label for your extra tick gets `xshift=2pt` twice. Once from `ticklabel style`, and a second one from the `extra y tick style={ticklabel style={..}}`. So if you remove the `xshift` from the `extra y tick style`, the position is the same. Complete example, with most of the unnecessary bit removed, and a vertical red line to highlight the alignment of the ticklabels. I also added `draw`, to make it easier to see the position of the ticklabel.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}    
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=5cm,name=a,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-3,ymax=3,
    ticklabel style={
      draw, % added just for example
      anchor=south east,
      xshift=2pt,
      yshift=-2pt, % you have -2pt here
      font=\tiny
    },
    xtick={\empty},ytick={2},
    extra y ticks={-2},
    extra y tick style={
         tick label style={
             anchor=north east,
             xshift=0pt, % zero xshift here
             yshift=4pt, % 4pt here, 2pt to counter the -2pt from above, another 2pt to get the same shift
          }
     },
    extra y tick labels={\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}2},
]
\end{axis}

\draw [very thin,red] ([xshift=-0.4em]a.north) -- ++(0,-4cm); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## Overwriting style

As mentioned above, `ticklabel style` appends to an existing style. If you instead of `ticklabel style={` use `every tick label/.style={`, then the `every tick label style` is redefined completely, so you don't have to take into account cumulative shifts, but you have to repeat, for example, `font=\tiny`. Here is an example, the output is the same as above.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=5cm,name=a,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-3,ymax=3,
    ticklabel style={
      draw, % just for example
      anchor=south east,
      xshift=2pt,
      yshift=-2pt, 
      font=\tiny
    },
    xtick={\empty},ytick={2},
    extra y ticks={-2},
    extra y tick style={
         every tick label/.style={
             draw, % just for example
             anchor=north east,
             xshift=2pt, % 2pt here as well
             yshift=2pt, 
             font=\tiny
          }
     },
    extra y tick labels={\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}2},
]
\end{axis}

\draw [very thin,red] ([xshift=-0.4em]a.north) -- ++(0,-4cm); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the first time I have seen a specification implemented cumulatively.

Comment: In my post, I should specify `yshift=2pt` in `extra y tick style` so that `-2` is typeset the same distance from `(0,-2)` as `2` is typeset the same distance from `(0,2)`.

Comment: Is that correct?

Comment: @Adelyn Probably 4pt then, 4pt - 2pt = 2pt.

Comment: @Adelyn Just updated my answer by the way.